# Redirecting to view or call void method from same controller ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I have a controller that should either return a view or run a void method that is contained in the same controller, is this possible? If so what type should the controller be?

Answer (score 3):

All controller actions must return ActionResults. You could call as many void methods as you wish but at the end of the day you must return an action result. Remember that this controller action was invoked using an HTTP request and you should accomplish your part (the server) from this protocol by returning a proper response to the caller which in ASP.NET MVC is accomplished by returning action results from controller actions. Could be view results, redirect results, file results, json results, custom results, ...

This being said having *void methods* in a controller is bad practice. A controller should contain actions. *Methods* usually belong to other layers of your application such as repositories, service layers, models, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can call this from anywhere in your code, as long as MyVoidMethod is static.

```
Controllers.MyController.MyVoidMethod(myParameter1, myParameter2);
```